# Getting Error "Incorrect syntax near ENspid" "Incorrect syntax near smoEnabled" while connecting Remote database via SSMS 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

[image: SSMS Error]

While trying to connect to Remote database via SQL Server management studio 2012 using SQL Server authentication, getting error shown in snapshot. But, it is working fine with the local database, with SQL server authentication. It is happening only on my system, tried to login via another system it is working fine, don't know why this issue is coming, I tried to google it but couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 2):

After, lot of research found the solution, actually the problem occur due to the Killer Center Application which is running on my laptop, for the prioritizing the bandwidth for the application, for improving the performance of Gaming. So, for resolving the issue, I open the Killer center app and given Sql server management studio as priority 1 for giving SSMS full bandwidth. After, that I tried to connect, it successfully got connected to the database.

Also, after googling I found out that these kind of issue occur due to faulty Ethernet/Wifi port. But, in my case it is due to Killer Center Application.